# What DLL search rules do calls using [DllImport] use?

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, interop

Calls decorated by [`[DllImport]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-5.0) somehow result in a search for the DLL, but I haven't found documentation specifying how that search is conducted.

[The Win32 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN) specifies at least the following DLL search modes:

1. Standard, SafeDllSearch enabled
2. Standard, SafeDllSearch disabled
3. Alternate, SafeDllSearchMode enabled
4. Alternate, SafeDllSearchMode disabled
5. Alternate, path specified
6. LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH Flags

The search order and other particulars seem to be well-specified for each of those search modes.  There are critical differences between those search modes, however, so I'd like to know which one is used by calls decorated with `[DllImport]`.

I suspect that the machinery invoked by those `[DllImport]` calls selects one of these search modes and let's the win32 bits do the searching; but I'm not even sure about that.  [The most detailed documentation I've found on the topic is rather vague](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions#a-closer-look-at-platform-invoke):

> When platform invoke calls an unmanaged function, it performs the following sequence of actions:
>
> 1. Locates the DLL containing the function.
> 2. Loads the DLL into memory.
> 3. Locates the address of the function in memory and pushes its arguments onto the stack, marshaling data as required.
> 4. Transfers control to the unmanaged function.

Comment: I seem to remember you can also call `LoadLibrary` yourself, and then P/Invoke will use whatever is already loaded.

Comment: Standard search order, as listed in the article.  Especially for pinvoke, there are excessively few good reasons to not deploy the dll in the directory that stores the .exe

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, that's something not frequently documented in the search order, but it's true that an already loaded DLL is found before any attempt is made to search the file system.  Another overlooked item is the registry database of `KnownDLLs`

Answer (score 2):

> I suspect that the machinery invoked by those [DllImport] calls selects one of these search modes and let's the win32 bits do the searching

It does let Win32 do the searching, but it doesn't select any of the modes.  Whatever search order is currently in effect for the current process will be used.  In particular, Safe DLL Search is controlled by the registry, not by .NET

Note that with `SetDefaultDllDirectories` and `AddDllDirectory` there are a lot more than 6 different search orders.

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile "...it doesn't select any of the modes...search order is currently in effect for the current process will be used..." with 
@HansPassant's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031120/what-dll-search-rules-do-calls-using-dllimport-use?noredirect=1#comment116746547_66031120) that the "Standard search order..." is used.  Do those two statements mean the same thing?

Comment: @alx9r: It doesn't specify any `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH` flag to pick an alternate search order.  You've called this "Standard" mode in the question (based on the process current search order it could become any of your bullets 1, 2, or 5).  Your bullet 6 seems to overlap your 3 and 4.

Comment: I see.  The search modes enumerated in the question correspond to the distinct listed desktop application search orders specified in [Microsoft's Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: @alx9r: At any given time, the process has two search orders defined, one standard and one alternate.  The registry entry `SafeDLLSearch` affects both of these, as described in that document.  Calls to `SetDllDirectory`, `SetDefaultDllDirectories`, `AddDllDirectory`, etc modify both of these.  p/invoke uses whatever is the process's current "standard" search order.